# The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript-3, object, movieclip, removechild, addchild

I keep getting this error:

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller.    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>     at Bell/eFrame()[C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\Bell.as:44]

My code:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
public class Bell extends MovieClip {

    var _root:Object;//this will symbolize the main timeline

    public function Bell() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
    }

    private function beginClass(e:Event):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);

        if(_root.bellTotal == 1){//if it's the first bell created
            this.x = Math.random()*525;//place it in a random spot on the stage
            _root.bellLastCoord = this.x;
        } else {//otherwise, 
            //In order to keep the next bell from being too far away from the previous bell, place it up to 250px away
            this.x = _root.bellLastCoord + (Math.random()*500)-250;
            if(this.x > 537.5){//if it is off the stage to the right
                this.x -= 250;//set it inside the stage
            } else if (this.x < 12.5){//same with too far left
                this.x += 250;
            }
        }
        this.y = _root.bellTop;//set the y's value off the stage
    }
    private function eFrame(e:Event):void{
        this.y += 3;//move the bell slowly downwards
        if(this.hitTestObject(_root.mcMain)){//if this touches the main character
            _root.mainJumping = true;//make him jump
            _root.jumpSpeed = _root.jumpSpeedLimit*-1;//reset the jumpSpeed
            _root.scoreInc += 10;//increase the amount that the score will increase
            _root.score += _root.scoreInc;//add this to the score
            var scoreText:ScoreAdd = new ScoreAdd();
            _root.bellHolder.addChild(scoreText);//add some text to the stage
            scoreText.x = this.x;//set the coordinates for the text
            scoreText.y = this.y;
            scoreText.txtScore.text = _root.scoreInc;//set the text to the amount the score increased by

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//remove the listeners
            _root.bellHolder.removeChild(this);//and finally remove him from the stage

            _root.startedJumping = true;
        }

        if(_root.gameOver){//if the game is over
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//remove the listeners
            _root.bellHolder.removeChild(this);//and remove from stage
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming line 44 is `_root.bellHolder.removeChild(this);`, this means that `this` (an instance of `Bell`) is *not* a child of `_root.bellHolder`.

When you add a new `Bell` to the display list, you need to make sure that you're adding it to `bellHolder`.

Comment: As an added point, the easiest, most fail-safe way to remove a child, no matter the `parent`, is `if( myChild.parent != null ) { myChild.parent.removeChild( myChild ); }`

Comment: @divillysausages While that will ensure you never see this error, it is a workaround and not a solution. You should fix the error, not workaround it. This is like a city closing down a road instead of fixing the pothole in the middle of it.